# inherent parallelism for a program

Tags: parallel-processing, execution

Hi I have a question regarding ***inherent parallelism***.

Let's say we have a sequential program which takes 20 seconds to complete execution. Suppose the execution time consists of 2 seconds of setup time at the beginning and 2 seconds of finalization time at the end of the execution, and the remaining work can be parallelized. How do we calculate the ***inherent parallelism*** of this program?

Comment: Maybe what you want to look at is the [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you define "inherent parallelism"?  I've not heard the term.  We can talk about "possible speedup".

OP said "*remaining work can be parallelized*"... to what degree?

Can it run with *infinite* parallelism? If this were possible (it isn't practical), then the total runtime would be 4 seconds with a speedup of 20/4 --> 5.

If the remaining work can be run on N processors perfectly in parallel,
then the total runtime would be  4+16/N.  The ratio of that to 20 seconds is 20/(4+16/N) which can have pretty much any degree of speedup from 1 (no speedup) to 5 (he the limit case) depending on the value of N.